# cipher shift to encrypt a number and letters

Tags: encryption

I am searching for a simple code that encrypt a random number and letters with cipher shift. Example: -3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz output xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that this is no encryption.
You are simply obfuscating the input. But this is being revealed quite easily.

Your question itself is very ambiguous. In what language do you want to look for? Please ask questions more specific.
Furthermore you could have look onto wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

This is what you want to do. The code itself comes with the language.

Best,
Bent